# How to stop infinite loop when user press ESC button in C# Windows forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, while-loop, task-parallel-library

I am pretty new to C#. Currently working on programming. I am facing a problem.

An infinite while loop is executing. I want loop should execute infinite time until user press <kbd>ESC</kbd> button. When <kbd>ESC</kbd> button pressed the loop should break.

You will think there lies such commands like `Console.KeyAvailable()`. But I am using windows forms. While using this command I received an error

> "cannot see if a key has been pressed when either application does not have a console"

So what should I do. I have searched some thing where I get to know to use either threading or Task parallel library. Since I am new so could you please tell me which is good for me threading or TPL.

When TPL should use and when threading should used?
Or is there any other command that can be used in replacement of `Console.KeyAvailable()`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please share with us the related piece of code in order to have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `KeyPreview` property of the Form to True, then check for Escape in the `KeyDown` event of the Form.  Note that this will only work while the form has FOCUS.  If you need this to work in other cases then you'll need to do a lot more work and use a low level keyboard hook via WH_KEYBOARD_LL (not trivial). In this example the infinite work is being done in the button1 handler via `async/await` and is cancelled with a simple flag. There are definitely more sophisticated ways to do this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
}

private bool cancel = false;

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cancel = false;
    button1.Enabled = false;
    while (!cancel)
    {
        label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    button1.Enabled = true;
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        cancel = true;
        label2.Text = "Cancel @ " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:MM:ss.ffff");
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```